# GitHub Actions not working strange error message

Tags: github, github-actions

So I get this error message for serveral github action runs:

```
The following team project collection is stopped: u58HQO13OlVT6yx9h86l8AENZAdSC6hwRnuQGH6RTqpb03FYH8. Start the collection and then try again. Administrator Reason: Creating Collection Host
```

The following is the workflow I am using:

```
name: Java docs deploy to gh-pages

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
      - docs-test

jobs:
  docs:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1
      - name: Set up JDK 1.11
        uses: actions/setup-java@v1
        with:
          java-version: 1.11
      - name: Docs with gradle
        run: ./gradlew javadoc
      - name: Build and Deploy
        uses: JamesIves/github-pages-deploy-action@releases/v3
        with:
          ACCESS_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.ACCESS_TOKEN }}
          BRANCH: gh-pages # The branch the action should deploy to.
          FOLDER: build/docs/javadoc # The folder the action should deploy.
```

I already tried rerunning it... Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies - this is an internal GitHub error message.  We were rolling out a new deployment that had errors for some workflows, and I'm afraid that yours was one of the workflows affected.

We've rolled that deployment back - if you run your workflow now, the problem should be resolved.  Apologies for the inconvenience!